Illegal Instruction Error in Docker Container Running Flask App with FAISS on Apple Silicon (M1)
Illegal Instruction Error in Docker Container Running Flask App with FAISS on Apple Silicon (M1)
Context:
I'm working on a Flask web application that uses FAISS for vector store, search, and retrieval as part of a Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) pipeline. The app runs inside a Docker container on an Apple Silicon (M1) machine and loads a precomputed FAISS vector store from a pickle file. It performs conversational retrieval using LangChain. To handle FAISS's amd64 architecture dependency, I'm using Docker's --platform linux/amd64 option for emulation.
Application Overview:
The application’s main functions include:

Extracting text from PDFs: The app reads uploaded PDF files and processes the text using PyPDF2.
Text Chunking: Text from the PDFs is split into chunks for efficient processing using LangChain’s CharacterTextSplitter.
Embeddings and Vector Search: These text chunks are then embedded into vector representations using OpenAI’s embeddings API. FAISS is used to store and retrieve these embeddings for similarity search.
Conversational AI: The app utilizes a conversational AI model (ChatOpenAI from LangChain) to retrieve responses from the vector store based on user queries. The conversation history is maintained using ConversationBufferMemory.
Handling User Input: The Flask app provides an API endpoint to handle user inputs. The application retrieves answers based on the vector similarity from the FAISS store and stores conversation history in the session.

Here’s a simplified version of the code:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, session
import pickle
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS

app = Flask(__name__)

vectorstore = None

def load_vectorstore():
   global vectorstore
   with open('vector_store.pickle', 'rb') as f:
      print("before loading")
      vectorstore = pickle.load(f)  # FAISS vector store is loaded here
      print("after loading")

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print("Starting")
   load_vectorstore()  # This triggers the FAISS loading
   print("After load vector code")
   app.run(debug=True)

The output from running the app inside the Docker container is as follows:
Starting
before loading
Illegal instruction

The error occurs when attempting to load the FAISS vector store with pickle.load(f). The container crashes with an Illegal instruction error right after printing "before loading".
This suggests that FAISS might be executing CPU-specific instructions that are unsupported on my Apple Silicon machine, despite the amd64 emulation.
Dockerfile:
The application is being containerized and run on a Mac M1 (ARM64). Given that FAISS requires amd64 architecture, I am building and running the image using QEMU emulation for cross-platform compatibility (linux/amd64 on linux/arm64).
# Use an Intel-based Python 3.11 image
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy only the required files first to leverage Docker layer caching
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY .env .
COPY app.py .
COPY htmlTemplates.py .
COPY vector_store.pickle .

# Install the dependencies specified in the requirements file
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . /app/

# Specify the command to run the application
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]

Troubleshooting:
Steps I've followed:

Ensured Docker Desktop Supports Multi-Platform Builds:

By making sure that experimental features are enabled:

Docker Desktop -> Settings -> Features in development
Enabled experimental features


Also enabled:

Docker Desktop -> Settings
General -> Use containerd for pulling and storing images
General -> Use Rosetta for x86_64/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon




Used QEMU and enabled binfmt_misc for multi-architecture support:

Ran the following to reset and install QEMU:
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes


Ran the following command to ensure binfmt_misc (binary format emulation) is enabled to ensure multi-architecture support:
docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install all




Built and ran the image with --platform linux/amd64 using the following commands:


docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t flask_py:2.0 .



docker run --platform linux/amd64 flask_py:1.0




Verified Build Metadata:
I also inspected the built image to verify its architecture from the metadata:
docker inspect flask_py:latest

Output:
.
.
"Architecture": "amd64",
"Os": "linux",
.
.



Tried Privileged Mode: I also tried running the container in privileged mode:
docker run --platform linux/amd64 --privileged flask_py:1.0

But the result was the same: "Illegal instruction."

Debugging with strace:
I used strace to get more details on the issue and observed the following repeated lines:
   [pid   140] [ Process PID=140 runs in 64 bit mode. ]
   [pid   140] [ Process PID=140 runs in x32 mode. ]
   [pid   140] +++ killed by SIGILL +++


Tested Platform Emulation:
A simple test with alpine returns x86_64, confirming that linux/amd64 is emulated correctly:
docker run --platform linux/amd64 --rm alpine uname -m



Key Question:
Given that FAISS might use AVX2 instructions (specific to amd64), which could be causing this Illegal instruction error on an ARM-based Mac, how can I run FAISS in this environment?
Specific Questions:

Are there known workarounds for running FAISS on Apple Silicon with amd64 emulation?
Are there specific QEMU or Docker configurations to better emulate amd64 CPU instructions on ARM-based M1 Macs?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Is it possible to recompile your x86-64 binaries with gcc -O3 -march=x86-64-v2 to avoid AVX?  (Or if recompiling, perhaps rebuild everything as native AArch64).  Rosetta2 won't emulate AVX or AVX2.  But yes if you can use QEMU instead of Rosetta, it can emulate AVX2 on ARM64.  (But beware that QEMU last I heard was sloppy about memory ordering for lock-free atomics when running x86-64 code on an AArch64 host, since it can't know which x86 loads/stores needed acquire/release, so it just gives them all relaxed semantics, except atomic RMWs.  So locking works.)

Apparently macOS 15 (Sequoia) will update Rosetta 2 to support AVX2 + FMA, and was available in beta in June, IDK what the current status is.  M1 doesn't have SVE, so I don't know how efficiently it translates code using 256-bit AVX vectors into AArch64 code using 128-bit vectors, but AArch64 does have twice as many vector regs as AVX so there is still just barely enough room to hold all the x86 vector register state.  But with nothing to spare to naively translate x86 memory-source instructions like vaddps ymm0, ymm1, [rdi] into separate load + add on AArch64.
